# Elasticsearch search length of array

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my object `profile`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "posts": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "create_date": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make a search: return all profiles which
1. have name "bob"
2. and have more than 5 posts

Here is an example that I found, but it does not work

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": "bob"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['posts'].values.size() > 5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get error `"reason":"Variable [posts] is not defined."`

---

update posts.id to keyword
`{"id": {"type":"text"},"fields":{{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}`

Same error

`"caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"compile error","script_stack":["doc[posts.id].values.size() > ...","    ^---- HERE"],"script":"doc[posts.id].values.size() > 5","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [posts] is not defined."}}}}]},"status":400`

Comment: Try with `doc['posts.id'].values.size() `

Comment: `doc['posts.id'].values.size()` -> same error `"reason":"compile error","script_stack":["doc[posts.id].values.size() > ...","    ^---- HERE"],"script":"doc[posts.id].values.size() > 5","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [posts] is not defined."}}}}]},"status":400`

Comment: The best thing to do in your case, is to add another field called `post_count` that you increment each time you add a new post. That will be much more performant going forth.

Comment: I think the way to go it's @Val  `post_count` field, but if you want to continue trying with scripted count. You will need to change `posts.id` to type `keyword` in order to be able to make `doc['posts.id'].values.size()`

Comment: Good point @jordivador `text` will not work in this case.

Comment: update posts.id as keyword -> same error (good to know this point :D ). Maybe like Thomas Decaux said, I have to add a check if exist ?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html this is because one document is missing the field `posts` (I suppose).

You could add a filter: "if field posts exists" or use in the script the condition "if doc.containsKey('posts')...."

Comment: even after adding the exits field it is giving the error{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "profile_company_experience"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['profile_company_experience'].values.length > 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}